# Spark ML- failing to load model using MatrixFactorizationModel

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to implement recommender system using Spark collaborative filtering.

First I prepare model and save to disk:

```
MatrixFactorizationModel model = trainModel(inputDataRdd);  
model.save(jsc.sc(), "/op/tc/model/");
```

When I load model using separate process the program fails with below exception:

**Code:**

```
   static JavaSparkContext jsc ;
    private static Options options;
    static{
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TC recommender application");
        conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
        jsc= new JavaSparkContext(conf);
     }
MatrixFactorizationModel model = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(jsc.sc(),
                "/op/tc/model/");
```

**Exception:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Not a file:
>   maprfs:/op/tc/model/data
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:324)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1952)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$aggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1114)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.aggregate(RDD.scala:1107)
>           at org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel.countApproxDistinctUserProduct(MatrixFactorizationModel.scala:96)
>           at org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel.predict(MatrixFactorizationModel.scala:126)
>           at com.aexp.cxp.recommendation.ProductRecommendationIndividual.main(ProductRecommendationIndividual.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:742)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Is there any configuration i need to set to load the model? any suggestion would be great help.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear. Your file does not exist (at least, it does not exist on the slaves since we can see it's doing a map operation)

Comment: if i load model on same process where i am saving it. it doesn't complain :(

Comment: On a side-node, I don't recommend the use of `allowMultipleContexts`. I have never seen it in the Spark configuration, which means it is still not well supported enough to expose it to the face of the world.

Comment: That makes sense right ? You just have a bug in your code that should be trivial to find. You're not loading the model where you think you are loading it, that's all. Can you share more code ?

Comment: I have validated both modules, the location is same. $ ls  /op/tc/model/    result: data  metadata

Comment: Do you pass `"/op/tc/model/data"` somewhere in the code or do you only pass `"/op/tc/model"` ? It's actually saying that this is a directory and not a file, I think

Comment: your first comment is life saver.. please put it in answer. the /op/tc/model/data was not present on slave nodes. Once i move directory manually using hadoop fs command then it works fine.

Comment: Glad it helped :) I added an answer which tries to be more genera than just this specific error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spark as in any other distributed computing framework, it is important to understand where the code runs when you are trying to debug it. It is also important to have access to various types. For example, in YARN, you would have:

- the master logs if your record them yourself
- the aggregated slave logs (thanks YARN, useful feature !)
- the YARN node manager (will for example tell you why a container was killed etc)
- etc

Digging into Spark issues can be quite time consuming if you don't look at the right place from the start. Now more specifically on this question, you have a clear stacktrace, which is not always the case, so you should use it to your advantage.

The top of the stacktrace is

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Not a file:
>   maprfs:/op/tc/model/data at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:324)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>   at

As you can see, the Spark job was executing a `map` operation when it failed. Who executes a `map` ? The slaves, therefore you have to make sure your file is available on all slaves, not only on the master.

More generally, you always need to make a clear distinction in your head between the code you are writing for the master and the code you are writing for the slaves. This will help you detecting this kind of interactions, as well as references to non-serializable objects and such common mistakes.